# Rails Shell Command - ERROR: UtilBindVsockAnyPort:284: socket failed 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, powershell, sockets

I'm building a Ruby on Rails application (on Windows 11 with Docker) that requires some command line execution. I've gotten this to a pretty good place, but I've hit a wall, and googling is bringing up little to nothing.

Whenever I try and access a .exe program with a shell command, it returns this error:

> ERROR: UtilBindVsockAnyPort:284: socket failed 1

This is my code in order to execute this command:

```
Dir.chdir('yt-dlp'){
        @command = Thread.new do
            @echoed = %x[#{"ls"}]
            %x[#{"./yt-dlp.exe [youtube-url] --extract-audio --audio-format mp3"}]
        end
        @command.join
    }
```

If I try and remove the **.exe** from ./yt-dlp, it returns an error that it can't find yt-dlp.

I suspect that this has something to do with my Docker environment, but even if it is, I am unsure of how to fix this. If anyone offers help, I will be extremely grateful! I'm sorry if this is not enough information to go off of.

Comment: Looks like a connection to port 284 is failing.  Either the service for port 284 is not running, another connection to the port is already running, there is no route to the IP address, or a virus checker (or firewall) is blocking port 284, the connection did not complete, or the connection stopped working while data was being transferred.

Comment: I found another case where UtilBindVsockAnyPort failed.  See : https://coder.social/mgbowen/windows-fido-bridge?force_isolation=true.  The failure was due to a connection not completing when using HTTPS and the TLS failed. It is like I said the connection is not completing, but this could be for thousands of different reasons.  You could use a sniffer to help isolate issue but it requires experience using the sniffer.  I would check log files and check Event Viewer to see if you can find more details.

Comment: Hey! I manage to finally fix my problem, thank you for the help! This pointed me in the right direction lol.